# Using return in ES6 generator function

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am having trouble finding out what happens if you use a return statement instead of yield.

```
function *gen(){

 const val = yield someAsyncFn();
 assert.equal(val,4);
 return val;

}
```

how does the return behave differently from the yield? I assume the return acts as a normal return statement, but the context of a generator function, does it also call `gen.return()` as well? Sort of confusing.

Perhaps the above is merely identical to this?

```
   function *gen(){

     const val = yield someAsyncFn();
     assert.equal(val,4);
     yield val;

   }
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`return` deliveres a return value for an iterators last iteration (when `done` equals `true`).

I've simplified your example a bit, since the async operation doesn't seem to be relevant to the question:

```
function *gen(){
 const val = yield 4;
 return val * 2;
}

var it = gen();
var val = it.next(); // { value: 4, done: false }
console.log(val.value); // 4
var res = it.next(val.value); // { value: 8, done: true }
console.log(res.value); // 8
```

Whereas without a `return` value, on the last iteration you will return a value of `undefined`:

```
function *gen2(){
 const val = yield 4;
 yield val * 2;
}

var it2 = gen2();
var val2 = it2.next(); // { value: 4, done: false }
console.log(val2.value); // 4
var res2 = it2.next(val2.value); // { value: 8, done: false }
console.log(res2.value); // 8
it2.next(); // { value: undefined, done: true }
```

*Sidenote:* As a rule of thumb, there is always one more `next` call then there are `yield` statements, which is why there is one more next call in the second example.

Let's say you're using a generator-runner like [`co`](https://github.com/tj/co), then the value you get after finishing the generator would be the value you `return`:

```
co(function* () {
  var result = yield Promise.resolve(true);
  return result;
}).then(function (value) {
  console.log(value); // value equals result
}, function (err) {
  console.error(err.stack);  // err equals result
});
```

**Important:** If you are iterating through an iterator, using a `for ... of` loop or something like `Array.from`, the `return` value is going to be ignored (Since you are doing async operations, this is probably not the case anyway):

```
function *gen(){
 const val = yield 4;
 return val * 2;
}

for (let value of gen()) {
  console.log(value);
}
// 4
```

In the end, calling a generator just creates an iterator. Whether the final value that the iterator returns is relevant, depends entirely on how you use it.

Comment: so if I want to return something besides "undefined" from a generator function, then I have to use "return" instead of yield? and what happens if there is a return statement before a yield statement? assume the yield statement would never be called.

Comment: 1. It really depends on how you run your generator. If you have an async flow with promises (using `co` or something similar), then the resolution value once your generator has finished running is going to be the value of your `return`. If you run it manually with `next`, you are free to decide what you do with the value of the last iteration. And if you use a loop to run it, `return` values are going to be ignored.

Comment: 2. A `return` statement always terminates the function call, even in generators. So no further statement (`yield` or other) will be executed after that.

Comment: Really helpful information, especially the last note regarding `for ... of` loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the thorough answer by @nils, there is one additional way to capture the return value of a generator function, namely as the value of `yield*` (necessarily inside another generator function):

```
  function* arrayGenerator(arr) {
    for (const element of arr) 
      yield element
    return arr.length
  }

  function* elementsFollowedByLength(arr) {
    const len = yield* arrayGenerator(arr);
    yield len;
  }
```

Note the first generator function which returns a value, after it is done yielding the array elements.

The second generator function, through `yield*`, causes the first generator function to yield all its values. When the first generator function is done and returns, that return value becomes the value of the `yield*` expression.

Comment: So this doesn't fit well in the comment field, and it isn't an answer, but it seems relevant: rather than creating another generator, it is possible to get the `return` value by manually iterating over the resulting iterator. So: `while (true) { const { value, done }  = await result.next(); console.log(value); if (done) break; }` ... you can use the `if (done)` statement with an `else` clause as well, if the final `return` value has a different type or requires a different action.