# What happens to data returned by saga functions?

Tags: javascript, react-redux, redux-saga

What happens to data returned by a `redux-saga` saga? Let's say we have this example code to fetch some categories:

```
import { REQ_CATEGORIES, getUserId, errCategories, recCategories } from './store'
import { call, put, select, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { getCategories } from './api'

export function* categoriesWorker() {
    try {
        const userID:string|undefined = yield select(getUserID)
        if (!userID) {
            throw new Error('No userID set')
        }
        
        const response:Category[]|null = yield call(getCategories, userId)
        if (!response) {
            throw new Error('Error fetching categories')
        }

        yield put(recCategories(response))
        return response
    }
    catch (e) {
        yield put(errCategories(e))
        return null
    }
}

export function* categoryWatcher() {
    yield takeEvery(REQ_CATEGORIES, categoriesWorker)
}

export default [categoryWatcher]
```

In my experience with `redux-saga` and `redux-thunk`, the real work is done by `put` or `dispatch` to get data into the `redux` store, which the components then pull using `import { connect } from 'react-redux'`.

The explicit return statement here has me guessing that I am missing something; what happens to data returned by the saga (the `return response` and `return null`)? Where does it go?

I've inherited this codebase from a non-responsive source, so I am unable to ask them if there is anything special they've done with this setup. From everything I've seen it looks like a fairly vanilla `react-native` + `redux` + `redux-saga` assembly. Here are the packages we're using, if it is relevant:

```
...
"react-redux": "8.1.1",
"redux": "4.2.1",
"redux-actions": "3.0.0",
"redux-persist": "6.0.0",
"redux-saga": "1.2.3",
"redux-saga-routines": "3.2.3",
"redux-thunk": "2.4.2",
...
```

Anyone know what happens to this data?

Comment: Does it answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37202369/using-return-in-es6-generator-function

Comment: That does help my understanding with generator functions in general, thank you for the reference! I am still interested in hearing if `redux-saga` does anything with the return value from the generator function, or if it is just discarded when the saga is finished.

Comment: One additional thing I've found in my codebase is that the return values from our sagas are being used by other sagas (one saga calls another saga and saves the yield value). So the return values at least in my case are important and cannot just be removed.